# How does one match character OR nothing using regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to take a block of numbers that may, or may not, have dividers and return them in a standard format.  Using SSN as an example:

```
ex1="An example 123-45-6789"
ex2="123.45.6789 some more things"
ex3="123456789 thank you Ruby may I have another"
```

should all go into a method that returns "123-45-6789"  Basically, anything(INCLUDING nothing) except a number or letter should return a SSN in a XXX-XX-XXXX format. The part that is stumping is a way to regular expressions to identify that there can be nothing.

What I have so far in IDENTIFYING my ssn:

```
def format_ssns(string)
  string.scan(/\d{3}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{1}\d{2}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}/).to_a
end
```

It seems to work for everything I expect EXCEPT when there is nothing.  "123456789" does not work. Can I use regular expressions in this case to identify lack of anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried to match 0 or 1 characters between your numbers?

```
\d{3}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{0,1}\d{2}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{0,1}\d{4}
```

Answer (score 64):

This has already been shared in a comment, but just to provide a complete-ish answer...

You have these tools at your disposal:

- `x` matches `x` exactly once
- `x{a,b}` matches `x` between `a` and `b` times
- `x{a,}` matches `x` at least `a` times
- `x{,b}` matches `x` up to (a maximum of) `b` times
- `x*` matches `x` zero or more times (same as `x{0,}`)
- `x+` matches `x` one or more times (same as `x{1,}`)
- `x?` matches `x` **zero or one time** (same as `x{0,1}`)

So you want to use that last one, since it's exactly what you're looking for (zero or one time).

```
/\d{3}[^0-9a-zA-Z]?\d{2}[^0-9a-zA-Z]?\d{4}/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex will allow `123-45[6789`, not to mention all kinds of Unicode characters and control characters. In the extreme case:

```
123
45師6789
```

is considered a matched by your regex.

You can use backreference to make sure the separator is the same.

```
/\d{3}([.-]?)\d{2}\1\d{4}/
```

`[.-]?` will match either `.`, `-` or nothing (due to the optional `?` quantifier). Whatever matched here will be used to make sure that the second separator is the same via backreference.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp... looks like I just found my own answer, but any clues for improvement would be helpful.

```
def format_ssns(string)
  string.scan(/\d{3}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{0,1}\d{2}[^0-9a-zA-Z]{1}\d{4}/).to_a
end
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: `{1}` is completely redundant and `{0,1}` is identical to `?` which is probably the answer to your question.

Comment: Actually where you have `{1}` you probably meant `?` as well.