# How to detect if the user inputs a fraction

Tags: java

I want to only accept fractions.

Here's what I've done so far:

```java
if (nm == 2) {
    System.out.print("First Fraction: ");
    aa = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Second Fraction: ");
    bb = sc.nextLine();

    if (aa.startsWith("[0-9].*") && aa.contains("/") && aa.endsWith("[0-9].*") && bb.startsWith("[0-9].*") && bb.contains("/") && bb.endsWith("[0-9].*")) {
        ar = new Arithmetic_Operations(aa, bb);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please Input Fraction");
        System.out.println();
        break;
    }
}
Arithmetic_Operations.Add();
```

How do I detect that the String starts and ends with a number?
Also, I have no idea what I was doing with the .start and .end codes.

Comment: The [startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) and [endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) methods do not treat their arguments as regular expressions.  The arguments are just literal prefixes and suffixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect simple fractions, you can use below method.

```java
public static boolean isFraction(String text){
    return  (text.matches("[0-9]+[/][0-9]+"));
}
```

If you want a more complex solution, you need to also check,

1. +, - signs
2. Parentheses
3. More than one /
4. Fractions

If you are implementing these via regex, below link will help you.

[Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079645/how-does-one-match-character-or-nothing-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

The question can be expressed more generally as "how to write a parser". Generally speaking, regex is not the most straightforward way to tackle it. See [here](https://lisperator.net/pltut/parser/) for a more thorough explanation, which can be summarized in your case as follows:

Write a method to check that the input has exactly:

- a numerator
- a denominator
- a division sign between them

This is a pretty simple case, so it'd be overkill to write something really complicated for it but one approach without using regex and with three separate simple "functions" (steps) would be the following:

```
boolean isFraction(String text) {
    String[] numeratorAndDenominator = text.split("/");
    // check for the division sign
    if (numeratorAndDenominator.length != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    // check that the numerator is an integer
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(numeratorAndDenominator[0].trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    // check that the denominator is also an integer
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(numeratorAndDenominator[1].trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For more complicated stuff it would probably be more worth your time to look at existing parsing libraries for mathematical expressions. One possibility might be [mathparser](http://mathparser.org/).